# How does one parameterize the surface formed by a *real paper* Möbius strip?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, differential-topology, minimal-surfaces

Here is a picture of a Möbius strip, made out of some thick green paper:

[image: Möbius strip]

I want to know either an explicit parametrization, or a description of a process to find the shape formed by this strip, as it appears in the picture. Now before you jump up and declare, "That's easy! It's just $\left(\left[1+u \cos \frac \theta2\right]\cos \theta,\left[1+u\cos\frac \theta2\right]\sin \theta,u\sin \frac \theta2\right)$ for $u\in\left[-\frac12\!,\frac12\right]$, $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$!" Understand that this parametrization misses some features of the picture; specifically, if you draw a line down the center of the strip, you get a circle, but the one in the picture is a kidney-bean shape, and non-planar. What equations would I need to solve to get a "minimum-energy" curve of a piece of planar paper which is being topologically constrained like this? Is it even true that the surface has zero curvature? (When I "reasonably" bend a piece of paper into a smooth shape, will it have zero curvature across the entire surface, or does some of paper's resistance correspond to my imparting non-zero curvature to the surface?)

This question is thus primarily concerned with the equilibrium shapes formed by paper and paper-like objects (analogous to minimal surface theory in relation to soap-bubble models). Anyone know references for this topic?

Comment: I upvoted for the "before you jump up and declare…" part because that's exactly what I was on the point of doing.

Comment: +1 for the sheer aesthetic pleasure given by your  picture.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an analysis of the shape of a *non*-twisted loop of paper. Also, I wonder how much of the kidney shape is the result of the upward force from the table and downward force of gravity? Have you tried suspending the strip from a string? How would the shape be different in zero gravity?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217670/is-there-a-mathematical-theory-of-physical-knots) seems incidentally related, although I found the responses to it unsatisfying.

Comment: This is just essentially a curve-fitting problem, rather than a math problem. I doubt there is a useful paramatrization other than a piece-wise approximation

Comment: @MJD Feel free to ignore gravity. I don't think it has a significant effect on the shape of the paper, but if anything it would work to make it *more* planar. Also, a non-twisted loop of paper is obviously cylindrical, from symmetry, but I imagine the proof of that would get you 90% of the way to this shape.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg That picture is courtesy of Wikipedia, and I agree. At first I thought it was somehow made seamless, but in the image description it says there is a hidden tape mark. I can't tell, though, in any case.

Comment: @Thomas I am looking more for the differential equation that *would* give the exact shape, even if no analytic solution exists. There is no reason the solution will not be smooth, at least looking at the picture, especially if you ignore gravity and the force from the table.

Comment: So you don't want the exact curve represented here? Because you go out of your way to say you want the exact curve here. The set of constraints on your problem are a physics problem. The math problem inherent here is, given a set of constraints, what would the equation be? As such, you haven't given us a math problem, but a physics problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The content of your previous comment seemed to indicate that you wanted to fit the image with a spline of some sort. Although that would *look* good, it would not have any fundamental reasons to back it up other than an appeal to the physical model in the photo. Although this is largely a physics problem, I am looking for the math behind it, similar to the theory of minimal surfaces, which most will agree has many mathematical curiosities, even though it *originally* stemmed from an actual physical situation.

Comment: My point is that, absent knowledge of the material properties of paper, we probably cannot give you a mathematical answer. And questions about what the material properties of paper are outside the scope of this group, so, unless you give us a *mathematical* problem (by specifying some (possibly idealized) material properties of paper,) we cannot give you a mathematical answer.

Comment: The stiffness of the paper is $1$, the thickness is $0$, the width is $1$, the length is $2\pi$. Pick your favorite units. I *know* that the final shape of the paper does not depend on the actual stiffness of the paper, but only on the fact that the paper is homogeneous.

Comment: This is an intriguing problem, but I agree with Thomas Andrews that we need input from physicists first. What integral gives us the total tension? (that we are supposed to minimize, I guess) Furthermore, an idealistic paper with an idealistic `join/glue' would still have a group of symmetries amounting to adding a constant to your parameter $\theta$ (modulo $2\pi$). But the solution manifestly does not have that symmetry! So some kind of spontaneous breaking of symmetry would have to happen, or may be the seam affects the equation after all?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am a physics ignoramus, but I imagine that there is an unstable symmetrical solution, which, slightly perturbed, becomes a configuration that collapses into a stable asymmetrical solution that is a member of a symmetrical *family* of configurations; exactly which one depends on the perturbation. I suppose the situation is analogous to that of a perfectly symmetrical pencil balanced on end. Which way does it fall? The pencil doesn't fall until it is perturbed, and it is the perturbation which breaks the symmetry.

Comment: The nature of the curve is that it has to preserve, locally, distance and angles. In particular, given any $u_0\in[-\frac 1 2,\frac 1 2]$, the path traced by $(u_0,\theta)$ as $\theta$ runs over $[0,2\pi]$ must be $2\pi$. So the "wrong answer" you give above, I think, can be shown to be wrong because this isn't true for it. (Note, that path is not closed, unless $u_0=0$.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It would be better, in light of the Mobius strip's topological peculiarities, to measure the path $(u_0,\theta)$ for $\theta\in[0,4\pi]$, and check for it to equal $4\pi$. I agree about that characterization of the surface (the parametrization is locally an isometry), but how do you characterize the second derivative? I have in my mind a Hessian matrix, and I want to say that one eigenvalue is 0 and the other has some differential equation governing how it changes over the surface, but I'm unsure about the specifics.

Comment: Actually, the "real" statement of this constraint is that the paper has zero elasticity - that is, the length of a path drawn on the "flat" rectangle is the length of the same path drawn on the twisted version in $3$-space. This is a minimal requirement, and doesn't rely on anything other than local properties of the map. It doesn't have anything to do with minimizing the tension of the map, however.

Comment: Thinking a bit about what @MJD said about gravity/table affecting the shape. I, too, think that we cannot ignore it. Table and gravity **do** affect an untwisted loop of paper **if** that 'cylinder' is lying flat on the table. The circular cylinder will then become very elongated. A long enough strip will touch itself in the middle along two line segments with constant $\theta$. From the posted image I get the impression that curvature is higher in the part furthest away, where a *$\theta=$ constant* line is parallel to the table, and where we might expect gravity to bend the paper more.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In the example you're thinking of, there will be a large portion of the strip contacting the table, and a section that hangs down in the middle. In this case, the hanging section is affected mostly because of it's weight, as you say, but notably, it is being supported on the side loops, with a contact point under them. In this case, there are only two contact points, and the rest of the loop is being supported from that. Thus, the near and far parts of the loop will hang down more if the force of gravity were to increase, not the other way around.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Möbius strip you show is a developable surface. No one, as far as I know, has been able to create a parametrization of it.

Since 1858, when the Möbius strip was discovered, mathematicians have been looking for a way to model it. The problem was finally solved in 2007 by E.L. Starostin and G.H.M. van der Heijden.

You might want to read their paper "The equilibrium shape of an elastic developable Möbius strip" by going to this site - http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucesgvd/pamm.pdf

Comment: Wow! I can't believe someone's really looked into this in that much detail. +2! Also, it seems like they did a good job of a parametrization of the surface, since they have plots.

Comment: The standard parameterization I saw in university was something like the one given by Wikipedia, or by the original question in this post: 
$$x(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u\\
y(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u\\
z(u,v)= \frac{v}{2}\sin \frac{u}{2}.$$  It seems clear that this parametrization has everywhere-zero curvature.  Why do you say “No one… has been able to create a parametrization of it.”?

Comment: Pinging @MJD because Wayne's second answer appears to be targeted at you. As for why the "usual" parameterization is not developable, I am not very good at calculating Gaussian curvature for a parameterization, so I can't say directly, but an easy way to see that it cannot lay flat is to consider a cut at $u=0$. The center line has length $2\pi$, but the edge lines each have length $2\pi(1+v_0^2/32+O(v_0^4))$, and there is no way for a flat surface to have both sides longer than the center. If anything, it is probably developable to a helicoid, but not a plane.

Answer (score 1):

MJD, since you refer back to the original question, and given your previous comments, I assume you are trying to be provocative.

However, your question does address a very common misconception. In a sense, the same one addressed by the original question.

It is common to think that the Mobius strip that can be modeled by giving a strip of paper a half-twist and joining the ends is described by the parametrization you give.

There are some very real differences between the two that help explain why this isn't so.

FIRST

The parametrization describes a Mobius strip whose center line is a circle.The paper model is like the recycling symbol and has a triangular center line.

SECOND

The parametrization describes the path of a straight line centered on a circle; the straight line travels around the circle and completes a single 180 degree rotation (half twist) by the time it returns to its starting point. At no time is the straight line ever bent in 3D space.

If you draw straight lines crosswise on a strip of paper, then make a model of a Mobius strip, you will discover that in the three corners those lines are bent in 3D space. If you take the time to look seriously at those corners you will discover that each one incorporates a half twist. So a paper Mobius strip actually has three half twists.

THIRD

If you cut the paper model in half crosswise, it will revert to being a flat strip of paper. The Mobius strip being modeled is therefore developable.

If you cut a model of the parametrization in half, it will not lie flat. It is not developable.

To answer your question, the reason I say no one has created a parametrization of a developable Mobius strip, is because as far as I know no one has. As I pointed out, E.L.Starostin and G.H.M. van der Heijden have been able to mathematically model a developable Mobius strip; but their model is not a simple parametrization.

I suggest you go back to your university and point out that they missed the boat on this one. It's as if they told you that topologically a cube, a sphere, and a tetrahedron were the same, then said the formula for a cube describes them all.

By the way, these are not the only two geometrical forms a Mobius strip can take. There are more out there still waiting to be modeled mathematically.

Comment: You didn't make it obvious in this post, but the triangular "recycle sign" Mobius strip is only developable away from the three folds, so it is not a true solution. The true solution must be bent in 3D space. As for "three half twists", that is a choice as well. The photo in the OP contains one half twist, and (as long as the width is sufficiently small compared to the loop length) there are solutions for any odd number of half-twists (well, even for an even number of half twists, but then it's not a Mobius strip).

Comment: Mario, thank you for pointing out to MJD that reason the "parametrized" Mobius strip won't lie flat when cut is the ration of the length of the side to the center line. I fell asleep at the switch on that one.

Comment: Actually, I'd love to see how to make that argument rigorous, especially since there is no assumption that the final shape of the flattened surface is a rectangle, although it's not hard to see that the short ends are straight lines and the two sides are curves of some sort which are separated by no more than the strip width.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be provocative.  By March 2014 I had forgotten what I had said back in December of 2012.

Comment: Wayne, I encourage you to click the `contact us` link at the bottom to get your two accounts merged. This can help the organization of these answers, and why not?